# Field _________ in required a bean of type _________ that could not be found

Tags: java, spring-boot, api, rest, intellij-idea

Working in intellij community edition.
How can i resolve this error. I have tried everything i could find on stackoverflow

**Console**

```
C:\Users\dell\.jdks\openjdk-17.0.2\bin\java.exe "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2021.3.1\lib\idea_rt.jar=60395:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2021.3.1\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath C:\Users\dell\OneDrive\Desktop\dailyWagers\target\classes;C:\Users\dell\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-data-jpa\2.6.3\spring-boot-starter-data-jpa-2.6.3.jar;C:\Users\dell\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-aop\2.6.3\spring-boot-starter-aop-2.6.3.jar;C:\Users\dell\.m2\repository\org\aspectj\aspectjweaver\1.9.7\aspectjweaver-1.9.7.jar;C:\Users\dell\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-jdbc\2.6.3\spring-boot-starter-jdbc-2.6.3.jar;C:\Users\dell\.m2\repository\com\zaxxer\HikariCP\4.0.3\HikariCP-4.0.3.jar;C:\Users\dell\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-jdbc\5.3.15\spring-jdbc-5.3.15.jar;C:\Users\dell\.m2\repository\jakarta\transaction\jakarta.transaction-api\1.3.3\jakarta.transaction-api-1.3.3.jar;C:\Users\dell\.m2\repository\jakarta\persistence\jakarta.persistence-api\2.2.3\jakarta.persistence-api-2.2.3.jar;C:\Users\dell\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\validator\hibernate-validator\6.2.0.Final\hibernate-validator-6.2.0.Final.jar;C:\Users\dell\.m2\repository\jakarta\validation\jakarta.validation-api\2.0.2\jakarta.validation-api-2.0.2.jar;C:\Users\dell\.m2\repository\org\jboss\logging\jboss-logging\3.4.3.Final\jboss-logging-3.4.3.Final.jar;C:\Users\dell\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\classmate\1.5.1\classmate-1.5.1.jar;C:\Users\dell\.m2\repository\org\springframework\data\spring-data-jpa\2.6.1\spring-data-jpa-2.6.1.jar;C:\Users\dell\.m2\repository\org\springframework\data\spring-data-commons\2.6.1\spring-data-commons-2.6.1.jar;C:\Users\dell\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-orm\5.3.15\spring-orm-5.3.15.jar;C:\Users\dell\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-context\5.3.15\spring-context-5.3.15.jar;C:\Users\dell\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-tx\5.3.15\spring-tx-5.3.15.jar;C:\Users\dell\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-beans\5.3.15\spring-beans-5.3.15.jar;C:\Users\dell\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\slf4j-api\1.7.33\slf4j-api-1.7.33.jar;C:\Users\dell\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-aspects\5.3.15\spring-aspects-5.3.15.jar;C:\Users\dell\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-security\2.6.3\spring-boot-starter-security-2.6.3.jar;C:\Users\dell\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter\2.6.3\spring-boot-starter-2.6.3.jar;C:\Users\dell\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot\2.6.3\spring-boot-2.6.3.jar;C:\Users\dell\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-autoconfigure\2.6.3\spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.6.3.jar;C:\Users\dell\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-logging\2.6.3\spring-boot-starter-logging-2.6.3.jar;C:\Users\dell\.m2\repository\ch\qos\logback\logback-classic\1.2.10\logback-classic-1.2.10.jar;C:\Users\dell\.m2\repository\ch\qos\logback\logback-core\1.2.10\logback-core-1.2.10.jar;C:\Users\dell\.m2\repository\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-to-slf4j\2.17.1\log4j-to-slf4j-2.17.1.jar;C:\Users\dell\.m2\repository\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-api\2.17.1\log4j-api-2.17.1.jar;C:\Users\dell\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\jul-to-slf4j\1.7.33\jul-to-slf4j-1.7.33.jar;C:\Users\dell\.m2\repository\jakarta\annotation\jakarta.annotation-api\1.3.5\jakarta.annotation-api-1.3.5.jar;C:\Users\dell\.m2\repository\org\yaml\snakeyaml\1.29\snakeyaml-1.29.jar;C:\Users\dell\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-aop\5.3.15\spring-aop-5.3.15.jar;C:\Users\dell\.m2\repository\org\springframework\security\spring-security-config\5.6.1\spring-security-config-5.6.1.jar;C:\Users\dell\.m2\repository\org\springframework\security\spring-security-web\5.6.1\spring-security-web-5.6.1.jar;C:\Users\dell\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-expression\5.3.15\spring-expression-5.3.15.jar;C:\Users\dell\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-web\2.6.3\spring-boot-starter-web-2.6.3.jar;C:\Users\dell\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-json\2.6.3\spring-boot-starter-json-2.6.3.jar;C:\Users\dell\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-databind\2.13.1\jackson-databind-2.13.1.jar;C:\Users\dell\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-annotations\2.13.1\jackson-annotations-2.13.1.jar;C:\Users\dell\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-core\2.13.1\jackson-core-2.13.1.jar;C:\Users\dell\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\datatype\jackson-datatype-jdk8\2.13.1\jackson-datatype-jdk8-2.13.1.jar;C:\Users\dell\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\datatype\jackson-datatype-jsr310\2.13.1\jackson-datatype-jsr310-2.13.1.jar;C:\Users\dell\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\module\jackson-module-parameter-names\2.13.1\jackson-module-parameter-names-2.13.1.jar;C:\Users\dell\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-tomcat\2.6.3\spring-boot-starter-tomcat-2.6.3.jar;C:\Users\dell\.m2\repository\org\apache\tomcat\embed\tomcat-embed-core\9.0.56\tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar;C:\Users\dell\.m2\repository\org\apache\tomcat\embed\tomcat-embed-el\9.0.56\tomcat-embed-el-9.0.56.jar;C:\Users\dell\.m2\repository\org\apache\tomcat\embed\tomcat-embed-websocket\9.0.56\tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.56.jar;C:\Users\dell\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-web\5.3.15\spring-web-5.3.15.jar;C:\Users\dell\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-webmvc\5.3.15\spring-webmvc-5.3.15.jar;C:\Users\dell\.m2\repository\mysql\mysql-connector-java\8.0.28\mysql-connector-java-8.0.28.jar;C:\Users\dell\.m2\repository\org\projectlombok\lombok\1.18.22\lombok-1.18.22.jar;C:\Users\dell\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-core\5.3.15\spring-core-5.3.15.jar;C:\Users\dell\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-jcl\5.3.15\spring-jcl-5.3.15.jar;C:\Users\dell\.m2\repository\org\springframework\security\spring-security-core\5.6.1\spring-security-core-5.6.1.jar;C:\Users\dell\.m2\repository\org\springframework\security\spring-security-crypto\5.6.1\spring-security-crypto-5.6.1.jar com.burrows.dailyWagers.DailyWagersApplication

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v2.6.3)

2022-02-04 23:09:16.239  INFO 1328 --- [           main] c.b.dailyWagers.DailyWagersApplication   : Starting DailyWagersApplication using Java 17.0.2 on DESKTOP-UNKQR00 with PID 1328 (C:\Users\dell\OneDrive\Desktop\dailyWagers\target\classes started by dell in C:\Users\dell\OneDrive\Desktop\dailyWagers)
2022-02-04 23:09:16.246  INFO 1328 --- [           main] c.b.dailyWagers.DailyWagersApplication   : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2022-02-04 23:09:19.421  INFO 1328 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2022-02-04 23:09:19.586  INFO 1328 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 114 ms. Found 1 JPA repository interfaces.
2022-02-04 23:09:21.367  INFO 1328 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8081 (http)
2022-02-04 23:09:21.408  INFO 1328 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2022-02-04 23:09:21.409  INFO 1328 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.56]
2022-02-04 23:09:21.621  INFO 1328 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2022-02-04 23:09:21.622  INFO 1328 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 5248 ms
2022-02-04 23:09:21.765  WARN 1328 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'controller': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'workerService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.burrows.dailyWagers.service.WorkerService' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
2022-02-04 23:09:21.771  INFO 1328 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2022-02-04 23:09:21.818  INFO 1328 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2022-02-04 23:09:21.881 ERROR 1328 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Field workerService in com.burrows.dailyWagers.controller.Controller required a bean of type 'com.burrows.dailyWagers.service.WorkerService' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
    - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.burrows.dailyWagers.service.WorkerService' in your configuration.


Process finished with exit code 1
```

**Controller.java**

```
package com.burrows.dailyWagers.controller;

import com.burrows.dailyWagers.model.Worker;
import com.burrows.dailyWagers.service.WorkerService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import java.util.List;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/workers")
public class Controller {

    @Autowired
    private WorkerService workerService;

    @GetMapping("/{workerType}")
    public List<Worker> getWorkers(@PathVariable String workerType){
        return this.workerService.getWorkers(workerType);
    }

    @GetMapping("/{id}")
    public Worker getWorker(@PathVariable Long id){
        return (Worker) this.workerService.getWorkers(String.valueOf(id));
    }

    @PostMapping("/{worker}")
    public void postWorker(@PathVariable Worker worker){
        this.workerService.postWorker(worker);
    }

    @PutMapping("/{worker}")
    public void updateWorker(@PathVariable Worker worker){
        this.workerService.updateWorker(worker);
    }

    @DeleteMapping("/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<HttpStatus> deleteWorker(@PathVariable Long id){
        try {
            this.workerService.deleteWorker(id);
            return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK);
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        }
    }
}
```

**WorkerService.java**

```
package com.burrows.dailyWagers.service;

import com.burrows.dailyWagers.model.Worker;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.List;

@Service
public interface WorkerService {
    public List<Worker> getWorkers(String workerType);
    public Worker getWorker(Long id);
    public void postWorker(Worker worker);
    public void deleteWorker(Long id);
    public void updateWorker(Worker worker);
}
```

**WorkerServiceImpl**

```
package com.burrows.dailyWagers.service;

import com.burrows.dailyWagers.model.Worker;
import com.burrows.dailyWagers.repository.WorkerRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

import java.util.List;

public class WorkerServiceImpl implements WorkerService{
    @Autowired
    private WorkerRepository workerRepository;

    public List<Worker> getWorkers(String workerType) {
        return workerRepository.findAll();
    }

    public Worker getWorker(Long id) {
        return workerRepository.getById(id);
    }

    public void postWorker(Worker worker) {
        workerRepository.save(worker);
    }

    public void deleteWorker(Long id) {
        Worker workerToBeDeleted = workerRepository.getById(id);
        workerRepository.delete(workerToBeDeleted);
    }

    public void updateWorker(Worker worker) {
        workerRepository.save(worker);
    }
}
```

**WorkerRepository.java**

```
package com.burrows.dailyWagers.repository;

import com.burrows.dailyWagers.model.Worker;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface WorkerRepository extends JpaRepository<Worker,Long> {
}
```

**Worker.java**

```
package com.burrows.dailyWagers.model;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat;

import javax.persistence.*;

import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.util.List;

@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Builder
public class Worker {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private String workerType;
    private String servicesOffered;
    private LocalDate availability;
    private Integer rating;
}
```

**application.properties**

```
server.port=8081

#mysql configuration
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/maid-app-db
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=5856
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

#hibernate configuration
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
```

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.3</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.burrows</groupId>
    <artifactId>dailyWagers</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>dailyWagers</name>
    <description>daily wagers web application</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: Please don't post junk in your question and don't ask for a solution "quickly". The site requires that you post sufficient text with your code so that you adequately *explain* your code and your problem. Trying to get around this by posting junk will invite close-votes and down-votes to your question because you are seen as not putting in effort to help make your question easier to answer.

Comment: Likewise, asking for answers "quickly" can be seen as you implying that your question is more important than the others on this site. We who answer are volunteers, and some feel that is quite presumptuous to imply this, again inviting down-votes and close-votes to your question. Have you gone through the [ask], [tour] and [help] links yet? If not, best to do so to learn how to best use this site.

Comment: Investigate your problem so that you know which bean is not being created. Then look at your code: How are you creating that bean? Can you think of any reason why what you are doing might not work? Then ask a specific question about that bean -- the error message tells you what type is the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I faced same issue when i was beginner in Spring Framework. If put `@Service` annotaion on interface then service interface become useless so, Remove `@Service` annotation from `WorkerService` and put this annotation in `WorkerServiceImpl`.